# addEventListener 'click' or 'touchstart' not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

Why is the following code failing to detect click/touch on mobile device (both Android and iPhone), whereas working fine in Chrome desktop developer-toggle mode? (it also works on the Android tablet for some reason)

Tried replacing 'click' with 'touchstart' with no luck.

```
    for (const item of document.getElementsByClassName('DotNavigation490254019__extendedRadioButton')) {
    console.log(item);
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('DotNavigation490254019__extendedRadioButton')[0].dataset['checked'] == 'true');

        if (document.getElementsByClassName('DotNavigation490254019__extendedRadioButton')[0].dataset['checked'] == 'true') {

            console.log('block');
            document.querySelector('#insert').style.display = 'block'

        }else{

            console.log('none');
            
            document.querySelector('#insert').style.display = 'none'

        }
        },100)
        
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide some `console` output on mobile?  If you are not ture how to find it on mobile, try [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/devtools-mobile) , or extensions like [vConsole](https://www.google.com/search?q=vConsole&oq=vConsole&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i60l5j69i65.1143j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try remote debugging and report back.